# Update Composer dependencies to latest despite static version numbers?

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, updates

Is it possible to update all my Composer dependencies to the latest versions via one command if I have used static version numbers? I'd like to keep the static version numbers but have them updated.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get composer to update version numbers to the latest ones available in composer.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197446/how-to-get-composer-to-update-version-numbers-to-the-latest-ones-available-in-co)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it possible to update all my Composer dependencies to the latest versions via one command, if I have used static version numbers?

In short: No, there is no command to automatically raise to the latest version for a given static version in `composer.json`, yet.

The closest you get is `composer outdated -D` (root package), which shows you the list of outdated packages on the root package, including `package`, `current version` and `latest version`. The next step would be to manually transfer the latest version numbers into the composer.json file.

---

If you want to automate this with a PHP script, then the following lines should get you started. The script raises all version numbers to latest, not only static ones. That means, you might want to add an additional check for static numbers, if you want to raise only those.

The script requires to run `composer outdated --direct > outdated.txt` on the CLI to produce the input file (or adjust the script to use exec/system/passthru/whatever and work on the the returned output directly).

!! Be careful and test this on an a standalone `composer.json` or a file under version control, where you can easily revert any unwanted modifications.

`update-composer-json-version-numbers-to-latest-version.php` or just `uv.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Raise/update static version numbers in composer.json.
 *
 * Run on the CLI: "composer outdated --direct > outdated.txt"
 */
$composerJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('composer.json'), true);

$listOfOutdatedPackages = file('outdated.txt');

foreach($listOfOutdatedPackages as $line) {

    $regexp = '/(?P<package>[\w-]+\/[\w-]+).*(?P<currentVersion>\d.\d.\d).*(?P<latestVersion>\d.\d.\d)/';
    preg_match($regexp, $line, $matches);
    $matches = array_filter($matches, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    if(isset($matches['package']))
    {
        $package = $matches['package'];

        if(isset($composerJson['require'][$package])) 
        {
            $currentVersion = $composerJson['require'][$package];
            echo sprintf('Updating %s from %s to %s', $package, $currentVersion, $matches['latestVersion']);
            $composerJson['require'][$package] = $matches['latestVersion']; 
        } 
        if(isset($composerJson['require-dev'][$package])) 
        {
            $currentVersion = $composerJson['require-dev'][$package];
            echo sprintf('Updating %s from %s to %s', $package, $currentVersion, $matches['latestVersion']);
            $composerJson['require-dev'][$package] = $matches['latestVersion']; 
        }              
    }
}

file_put_contents('composer.json', json_encode($composerJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

And now someone posts a nifty one-liner using grep/awk/sed... right? :)

Comment: Well this conflicts with the accepted answer ...

Comment: I wonder, how does the accepted answer "conflict with the accepted answer"?

Comment: the regular expression should be [\w-]+\/[\w-]+ instead of [\w]+\/[\w]+ as "-" is also allowed.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice job, please add   . "\n"   to the end of echo lines for user friendly output :)

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. Nowadays, you could use a combination of `composer show` and `composer require` (like in my answer) or a combination of `composer update` and `composer bump`, but this later approach won't update major versions depending on the constraints (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796309/1391963)

Answer (score 15):

I've had this issue many times, always search for an answer, but couldn't find one. Today I took the time to find a good solution for large `composer.json` files.

### tl;dr

Use these two commands to update all packages:

#### Required packages

```
composer require $(composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys | map(.+" ") | add' -r)
```

#### Developement packages

```
composer require --dev $(composer show -s --format=json | jq '.devRequires | keys | map(.+" ") | add' -r)
```

### Commands explained

First I found the list option for all composer packages (here at the example of `wp-cli/wp-cli`:

```
$ composer show -s
name     : wp-cli/wp-cli
descrip. : WP-CLI framework
keywords : cli, wordpress
versions : * 2.7.x-dev
type     : library
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://wp-cli.org
source   : []  a5336122dc45533215ece08745aead08af75d781
dist     : []  a5336122dc45533215ece08745aead08af75d781
path     : 
names    : wp-cli/wp-cli

support
issues : https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues
source : https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli
docs : https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/

autoload
psr-0
WP_CLI\ => php/
classmap
php/class-wp-cli.php, php/class-wp-cli-command.php

requires
php ^5.6 || ^7.0 || ^8.0
ext-curl *
mustache/mustache ^2.14.1
rmccue/requests ^1.8
symfony/finder >2.7
wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc ^0.6.3
wp-cli/php-cli-tools ~0.11.2

requires (dev)
roave/security-advisories dev-latest
wp-cli/db-command ^1.3 || ^2
wp-cli/entity-command ^1.2 || ^2
wp-cli/extension-command ^1.1 || ^2
wp-cli/package-command ^1 || ^2
wp-cli/wp-cli-tests ^3.1.6

suggests
ext-readline Include for a better --prompt implementation
ext-zip Needed to support extraction of ZIP archives when doing downloads or updates
```

Parsing this would not be easy. But fortuntely, we can use the `--format` argument to get it as JSON:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json
{
    "name": "wp-cli/wp-cli",
    "description": "WP-CLI framework",
    "keywords": [
        "cli",
        "wordpress"
    ],
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "https://wp-cli.org",
    "names": [
        "wp-cli/wp-cli"
    ],
    "versions": [
        "2.7.x-dev"
    ],
    "licenses": [
        {
            "name": "MIT License",
            "osi": "MIT",
            "url": "https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText"
        }
    ],
    "source": {
        "type": "",
        "url": "",
        "reference": "a5336122dc45533215ece08745aead08af75d781"
    },
    "dist": {
        "type": "",
        "url": "",
        "reference": "a5336122dc45533215ece08745aead08af75d781"
    },
    "suggests": {
        "ext-readline": "Include for a better --prompt implementation",
        "ext-zip": "Needed to support extraction of ZIP archives when doing downloads or updates"
    },
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli",
        "docs": "https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "WP_CLI\\": "php/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "php/class-wp-cli.php",
            "php/class-wp-cli-command.php"
        ]
    },
    "requires": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0 || ^8.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "mustache/mustache": "^2.14.1",
        "rmccue/requests": "^1.8",
        "symfony/finder": ">2.7",
        "wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc": "^0.6.3",
        "wp-cli/php-cli-tools": "~0.11.2"
    },
    "devRequires": {
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-latest",
        "wp-cli/db-command": "^1.3 || ^2",
        "wp-cli/entity-command": "^1.2 || ^2",
        "wp-cli/extension-command": "^1.1 || ^2",
        "wp-cli/package-command": "^1 || ^2",
        "wp-cli/wp-cli-tests": "^3.1.6"
    }
}
```

Now we need to parse the JSON and on my system I had the `jq` command available, which allows you to parse the JSON. I've found [a nice cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4) with some useful argument and was able to just the `requires` key:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires'
{
  "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0 || ^8.0",
  "ext-curl": "*",
  "mustache/mustache": "^2.14.1",
  "rmccue/requests": "^1.8",
  "symfony/finder": ">2.7",
  "wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc": "^0.6.3",
  "wp-cli/php-cli-tools": "~0.11.2"
}
```

Now we only need to get the keys of the object:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys'
[
  "ext-curl",
  "mustache/mustache",
  "php",
  "rmccue/requests",
  "symfony/finder",
  "wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc",
  "wp-cli/php-cli-tools"
]
```

Then we want to join all values into one large string, which we can do with `add`:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys | add'
"ext-curlmustache/mustachephprmccue/requestssymfony/finderwp-cli/mustangostang-spycwp-cli/php-cli-tools"
```

Oops! We need some whitespace. Let's add them using `map` before we use `add`:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys | map(.+" ") | add'
"ext-curl mustache/mustache php rmccue/requests symfony/finder wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc wp-cli/php-cli-tools "
```

OK, great! But how can we get rid of the double quotes? We use the `-r` argument:

```
$ composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys | map(.+" ") | add' -r
ext-curl mustache/mustache php rmccue/requests symfony/finder wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc wp-cli/php-cli-tools
```

Yeah! Now we have, what we needed. Let's put this in a sub-command and update all our packages:

```
$ composer require $(composer show -s --format=json | jq '.requires | keys | map(.+" ") | add' -r)
Using version * for ext-curl
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^2.14 for mustache/mustache
Using version ^7.4 for php
Using version ^2.0 for rmccue/requests
Using version ^5.4 for symfony/finder
Using version ^0.6.3 for wp-cli/mustangostang-spyc
Using version ^0.11.15 for wp-cli/php-cli-tools
./composer.json has been updated
...
```

That it! If your project also have dev requirements, you'll need to run a second command updating them as well by adding `--dev` to the first command and using `devRequires` instead of `requires` in the filter:

```
$ composer require --dev $(composer show -s --format=json | jq '.devRequires | keys | map(.+" ") | add' -r)
Using version dev-latest for roave/security-advisories
Using version ^2.0 for wp-cli/db-command
Using version ^2.2 for wp-cli/entity-command
Using version ^2.1 for wp-cli/extension-command
Using version ^2.2 for wp-cli/package-command
Using version ^3.1 for wp-cli/wp-cli-tests
./composer.json has been updated
...
```

I hope this helps everyone who regularly wants to update all packages

Comment: See my answer for a similar solution, not using `jq`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Make a list of all the packages in your `composer.json`
2. use `composer require [package name]` from your previous list
3. run each command, you can do so via automated or manual means

**Example**

Say your composer has `phpunit/phpunit` package among all others.  One of your commands will be

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit
```

That will automatically update the version in your `composer.json`.  In rare cases if you had a dev version of a package, it may downgrade the version to the latest stable.

Answer (score 4):

This is nowadays possible using `composer show` and `composer require`:

```
composer show --no-dev --direct --name-only | xargs composer require
```

For developer dependencies, it gets more tricky:

```
grep -F -v -f <(composer show --direct --no-dev --name-only | sort) <(composer show --direct --name-only | sort) | xargs composer require --dev
```

This is equivalent to what npm-check-updates ([ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)) would do for NPM.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't want exactly this (in most cases).

In general, to update all the packages, you need a bit more information: version constraints for all packages (should we use version 5, which brakes BC, if we are still using 3.x?), some packages may have special stability requirements (`@beta`, etc.).

So, `composer.lock` and `composer update` are there for this purpose. Use `composer.json` to define constraints (version ranges, stability levels) and `composer.lock` to "freeze" your deps.

If you use the scheme above, you can simply install "frozen" deps with `composer install` (it always uses versions from `composer.lock`) or update to latest with `composer update` (will update `composer.lock`).

Comment: Thanks, in my scenario I'm using composer for WordPress plugins so I want to update all to latest and then test to make sure there are no ill effects. I'd rather lock at a particular version rather than do a range so other developers can be sure that it was working with the given version.

Comment: You are welcome! But take a look from another side: if you are locking to specific versions in `composer.json`, then users of your library are stuck with the versions of shared deps.

For example, if your library is using Guzzle 6, and you specified 6.2.3 as the version in your `composer.json`, then end users cannot move from this version, even when they want to upgrade Guzzle in case of critical bug fix.

Comment: Thanks! Good point, but I'm using it to control WordPress plugin updates in this instance.

Comment: For code that is updated often and that is tested locally, and maybe that is not too complex (i.e. it does not have a crazy number of dependencies), I think updating to latest release works fine

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little composer [composer plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/chx/jump) which does exactly this. Make sure to version control your `composer.json` before trying it:

```
composer require chx/jump
composer jump
```